# While itemadd event works in my outlook it doesn't work in friends pc

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code which works in my system but not in my friend's PC. Both use the same Outlook version.

Here is the snippet.

```
Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

Private Sub start_Click() 

Dim objNS As nameSpace
  Set objNS = Application.Session
  ' instantiate objects declared WithEvents

  Call accessInbox(inbox)          // my own function 
  Set olInboxItems = inbox.Items
  'Set objNS = Nothing

  Me.Hide
End Sub   


Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  On Error Resume Next

  MsgBox "a Message recieved"
  'Call download(Item)
  Call multiSubjectDownload(Item)       //my own function 

End Sub
```

What may be the problem?

Are there settings that differ which prevent the code detecting new mail in inbox?

Answer (score 0):

i found the error i was n't referring to inbox. so event was  not firing because my item  event was on inbox  :)